# vSRX : several public addresses on loopback interface

Tags: bgp, juniper-junos, wan, juniper-srx

I have an issue when I try to configure several ip addresses on the loopback interface on a vSRX cluster.

Here is my setup (in gns3) :

[image]

vSRX-1 and 2 are in cluster mode.
VyOS-1 and 2 are BGP routers miming our actual ISP.
Each vSRX have active BGP session with the corresponding VyOS router; this setup is for redundancy only (no load balancing). vSRX-1 and VyOS-1 share a /30 network and vSRX-2/VyOS-2 share another /30.

Our ISP gave us a private as number and we announce a /28 network via BGP.

Concerning our cluster setup :

As reth interface can be active on only one node at a time, WAN interfaces are non-reth. LAN interfaces are in redundancy groups.

Some public IP need to be hosted on vSRX (for destination nat and VPN), as WAN interfaces are non-consistent in case of failure, I need to set public IP addresses on the loopback interface.

Here comes the issue.

If I try the following setup

```
# show interfaces lo0        
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address X.X.6.97/28;
        address X.X.6.98/32;
    }
}
```

Commit fails with the following error:

```
# commit 
error: Overlapping subnet is configred under lo0
[edit interfaces lo0 unit 0 family inet]
  'address X.X.6.98/32'
     Overlapping subnet is configured 
error: configuration check-out failed
```

And if I try the following configuration

```
# show interfaces lo0 
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address X.X.6.97/28;
        address X.X.6.98/28;
    }
}
```

The route is correctly mounted but lo0 has only one IP:

```
# run show route
[..]
X.X.6.96/28    *[Direct/0] 16:56:19
                    > via lo0.0
X.X.6.97/32    *[Local/0] 16:56:19
                      Local via lo0.0
[..]
# run show interfaces lo0.0 terse           
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
lo0.0                   up    up   inet     X.X.6.97/28
```

And if I try:

```
# show interfaces lo0 
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address X.X.6.97/32;
        address X.X.6.98/32;
    }
}
```

lo0.0 has both IP but the route to X.X.6.96/28 is missing (and thus, not propagated by BGP) :

```
# run show interfaces lo0.0 terse   
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
lo0.0                   up    up   inet     X.X.6.97        --> 0/0
                                            X.X.6.98        --> 0/0
# run show route  
[..]
X.X.6.97/32    *[Direct/0] 00:01:43
                    > via lo0.0
X.X.6.98/32    *[Direct/0] 00:01:43
                    > via lo0.0
[..]
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong ?

Does the cluster design look good to you ?

*Update. BGP config:*

```
set routing-options autonomous-system 65000
set protocols bgp log-updown
set protocols bgp group PEER-PRIMARY type external
set protocols bgp group PEER-PRIMARY description "Peer primary"
set protocols bgp group PEER-PRIMARY log-updown
set protocols bgp group PEER-PRIMARY export PEER-PRIMARY-OUT
set protocols bgp group PEER-PRIMARY peer-as XX1
set protocols bgp group PEER-PRIMARY neighbor X.X.X.8 import PEER-PRIMARY-IN
set protocols bgp group PEER-SECONDARY type external
set protocols bgp group PEER-SECONDARY description "Peer secondary"
set protocols bgp group PEER-SECONDARY log-updown
set protocols bgp group PEER-SECONDARY export PEER-SECONDARY-OUT
set protocols bgp group PEER-SECONDARY peer-as XX1
set protocols bgp group PEER-SECONDARY neighbor X.X.X.4 import PEER-SECONDARY-IN
set policy-options prefix-list BGP-LAN X.X.6.96/28
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-PRIMARY-IN term DEFAULT then local-preference 100
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-PRIMARY-IN term DEFAULT then accept
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-PRIMARY-IN then reject
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-PRIMARY-OUT term LAN from prefix-list BGP-LAN
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-PRIMARY-OUT term LAN then accept
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-PRIMARY-OUT then reject
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-SECONDARY-IN term DEFAULT then local-preference 50
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-SECONDARY-IN term DEFAULT then accept
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-SECONDARY-IN then reject
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-SECONDARY-OUT term LAN from prefix-list BGP-LAN
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-SECONDARY-OUT term LAN then as-path-prepend 65000
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-SECONDARY-OUT term LAN then accept
set policy-options policy-statement PEER-SECONDARY-OUT then reject
```

*Update 2. address ordering*

As suggested by @Cown and described in https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Multiple-IP-s-on-the-loopback-interface-not-working/m-p/249710#M30768 IP ordering in interface lo0.0 doesn't work for me in vSRX 15.1X49-D80.4

```
# show interfaces lo0 unit 0 
family inet {
    address X.X.6.98/28;
    address X.X.6.97/32;
}
# commit
error: Overlapping subnet is configred under lo0
[edit interfaces lo0 unit 0 family inet]
  'address X.X.6.97/32'
     Overlapping subnet is configured 
error: configuration check-out failed
```

Comment: address X.X.6.97/28; and address X.X.6.98/32; are in the same subnet and overlapping each other, that's why you cannot commit.
x.x.6.98 is a network address under the x.x.6.97/28 subnet, the network spans from x.x.6.97-110.

Comment: You need to use: `# show interfaces lo0 
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address X.X.6.97/28;
        address X.X.6.98/28;
    }
}` x.x.6.97 and x.x.6.98 is announced via X.X.6.96/28 because they are part of that subnet.

Comment: @Cown thanks for your comments. I already tryed to put .97/28 and .98/28 but in that case, lo0.0 get only .97/28 and .98/28 is ignored. (see my post, 2nd case)

Comment: Could you post the full BGP configuration?

Comment: What is the task you're trying to solve? If you just want to announce /28, then simply make /28 static route with discard keyword and use two /32 for loopback.

Comment: @PierreEmile
Sorry been away, you need to reserve the order of the subnets, pretty sure it works then, remove config and do like this: address X.X.6.98/28;
address X.X.6.97/32;

Comment: @PierreEmile
Almost same problem posted on juniper forums: [https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Multiple-IP-s-on-the-loopback-interface-not-working/m-p/249710#M30768](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Multiple-IP-s-on-the-loopback-interface-not-working/m-p/249710#M30768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ar_ the solution is :

- configure ip addresses on lo0.0 with /32 mask
- set a discarded static route to /28 (network will then be propagated by BGP)

To go further :

- add lo0.0 in untrust zone
- set an intra-zone policy to allow 'external' traffic (ex. ping) since lo0.0 won't be the incoming traffic interface.

```
# show interfaces lo0 
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address X.X.6.97/32;
        address X.X.6.98/32;
    }
}
# show routing-options 
static {
    route X.X.6.96/28 discard;
}
[··]
# show security zones security-zone untrust 
[..]
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0.0 {
        host-inbound-traffic {
            system-services {
                ping;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-7/0/0.0 {
        host-inbound-traffic {
            system-services {
                ping;
            }
        }
    }
    lo0.0 {
        host-inbound-traffic {
            system-services {
                ping;                   
            }
        }
    }
}
# show security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust 
policy permit-ping {
    match {
        source-address any;
        destination-address any;
        application junos-ping;
    }
    then {
        permit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, i'm happy you got it working. That solution seems a lot better. :-)